# Encountering "List Index out of Range" Exception while Web Scraping via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-science, data-analysis

I'm scraping data for a data science project using Selenium, and I don't know why I get Index errors on the write-to-csv portion. When I print out the data as-is, the output looks normal.

Code below:

'''

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/filepath/geckodriver.exe")

url = 'https://website.com'

driver.get(url)

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', '\n')

ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="id-name"]')
id_list = []
for i in range(50):
    id_list.append(ids[i].text)
print(len(ids))
print(len(id_list))
print(id_list[0:50])

# Break up into batches to save memory
new_id_list = [id_list[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(id_list),5)]

#time.sleep(1200)

for i in range(len(new_id_list)):
    for j in range(len(new_id_list[i])):
        url = 'http://www.website.com?id=' + str(id_list[j])
        driver.get(url)
        col1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="field-value-col_1"]/span/span')
        col2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h1[@id="field-value-col_2"]')
        col3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="field-value-col_3"]')

        print(id_list[i][j] + ',' + col1[0].text + ',' + col2[0].text + ',' + col3[0].text, '\n')

# This is where I get the error usually.

        with open('bugzilla.csv', 'w') as f:
            f.write(id_list[i][j] + ',' + col1[0].text + ',' + col2[0].text + ',' + col3[0].text, '\n')


    print('Batch of 5')

f.close()
```

'''

Comment: So what happens if any of your driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...) statements returns an empty result?  You are hard-coding checks for element '0' for each one, but there's no guarantee that any/all actually have elements.

Comment: When I print the output I only see 'Element1', , 'Element3'. I guess I have to find a way to return a 'nan' string when that happens.

Comment: @JustinBurack, you can use the try/except to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here

`print(id_list[i][j] + ',' + col1[0].text + ',' + col2[0].text + ',' + col3[0].text, '\n')`

you work with your `id_list` as with two-dimensional array while earlier you define it as

```
id_list = []
for i in range(50):
    id_list.append(ids[i].text)
```

You probably meant: `print(new_id_list[i][j] + ',' + col1[0].text + ',' + col2[0].text + ',' + col3[0].text, '\n')`